# IBM MFP Adapter-based authentication without client-side components

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

How can i use MFP (8.0) adapter based authentication without installing mfp client sdk / libs. 
Is it possible to make REST call to the adpater (login) directly from the client application (mobile) without the client sdk.

**Updates:**
*I have tried confidential client option , but i need individual user details instead of pre-defined client id.*

Comment: Can you please clarify the requirement ? Why would you want to Call the Rest Adapter from a Mobile application without using Client SDK ?

Comment: @KavithaVaradarajan to avoid the dependency , in future if we need to change MFP with something else.

Comment: @ArjunTRaj, be specific - there is an "adapter based authentication" feature available until MFP 7.1. Then there is the security check adapter based authentication in MFP 8.0. Which one specifically are you referring to?

Comment: @VivinK MFP 8.0

Answer (score 0):

You can't make Adapter Based Authentication in your Client Application without MobileFirst SDK.

However this is possible only with unprotected adapter endpoint.

Comment: "However this is possible only with unprotected adapter endpoint" - Can you please tell me how ?
i don't want to use confidential client anyway

Comment: @ArjunTRaj Remove the OAuth Protection from the Adapter Endpoint. It will become unprotected REST endpoint which can be accessed from anywhere.

Comment: ok, But how can we access that adapter? 
suppose the default login adapter

@Path("/resource")
public class UserLoginSecurityCheck extends UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck {
...
}

how can i access this adapter via rest?
i tried xxxxx.xxx/resource but its not working

Comment: Are you trying to access Security Check Adapter or Resource Adapter ? Security Check Adapter can't be accessed via REST.

Comment: ok , can we access security check adapter from another resource adapter that is accessible from REST (unprotected)

Comment: No you can't, You need MFP SDK if you are using resource adapter endpoint protected with security check.

Answer (score 0):

Security check adapters cannot be accessed via REST calls. You can protect your resources with scopes mapped to these securitychecks and they get invoked when the resources are accessed. At the client, uou handle the challenges that come from the securitychecks. This needs the MFP Client SDK to be in place. You cannot access the securitycheck adapters directly without MFP client SDK.

There are two ways for you to avoid invoking a securitycheck:

1. Do not mark the resource with any security. In this case default security scopes get applied. However you still need MFP client SDK to handle the OAuth handshakes.
2. The only other way to avoid invoking security check adapters is to explicitly mark your resources un-protected ( disable OAuth security for that resource). This will prevent any challenge answer mechanism and you can access the resource without MFP client SDK. Do note that your resources (via REST endpoints) will be open to attack - there will not be any security applied on it.